How to programatically know if a token issuer can freeze my token account?
I have this bot written in Go that buys tokens as soon as they have liquidity deployed into Solana, and after the price reaches a target, it sells 100% of the token in the wallet.
Today I had the misfortune of getting the bot honeypotted, it bought from a LP that can freeze the token account of my bot. The token in question is https://dexscreener.com/solana/8hdtooepaqirxopz96n17kshucjf8xmhpakpwrhzz4na
I can see that Dex Screen alerts users with the following message: This token is freezable
Thus, I wonder, how can I figure out if such a thing can happen? For the bot to avoid buying anything with such a big red flag!

yes, you can check the freezeAuthority field of the mint and if it's anything other than null, then the owner can freeze the tokens
On Typescript, this would look like this
async function getTokenAcc() {
    const mint = new PublicKey("Bw4L2GHeAGFN5ZmZoU7KhBNiLTfjduJVjKvT8BsnRPXH");

    const mintInfo = await getMint(connection, mint);
    const freezeAuth = mintInfo.freezeAuthority;

    if (!freezeAuth) throw new Error("owner hasn't revoked freeze authority");
}

getTokenAcc();

